# SQL: Greater than or equal to in where clause based on case condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to select such that if  `@reporteetype`  is `'immediate'` then I would want to select rows where level is **equal to** 1, otherwise where level is **greater than** 2.

```
select a, b, c, level
from table1
where col1 ='x' and                              
      CASE @reporteetype WHEN 'immediate' THEN level = '2'   
                         WHEN 'other' THEN level > 2
                         else 1 = 1
      END
```

This is a simplified version of my scenario. I do not want to use dynamic query. I want to know if this could be done using case?

Comment: Use `AND`/`OR` instead of `case` expressions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it using combinations of `AND` and `OR` conditions:

```
SELECT
    a, b, c, level
FROM table1
WHERE
    col1 = 'x'
    AND (
        (@reporteetype = 'immediate' AND level = 2)
        OR (@reporteetype = 'other' AND level > 2)
    )
```

Additional reading:

[Catch-all Queries by Gail Shaw](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/)

Comment: Always remember to wrap the OR statement in parentheses as Felix has, it can get confusing if you don't.

Answer (score 3):

Answer suggested by @Felix Pamittan is more efficient, however if you want to use CASE Expression, then it can be helpful:

```
SELECT  a
      , b
      , c
      , level
FROM    table1
WHERE   col1 = 'x'
        AND ( ( CASE WHEN @reporteetype = 'immediate' THEN '2'
                END ) = level
              OR ( CASE WHEN @reporteetype = 'other' THEN '2'
                   END ) > level
            )
```